# Multiprocessing advice and stop processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement a system where:

- `Actors` generate data
- `Replay` is a class that manage the data generated by the `Actors` (In theory it does much more than in the code below, but I kept it simple for posting it here)
- `Learner` use the data of the Replay class (and sometimes update some data of `Replay`)

To implement that, I appended my generated data of the Actors to a `multiprocessing.Queue`, I use a process to push my data to my Replay. I used a `multiprocessing.BaseManager` to share the `Replay`.

This is my implementation (the code is working):

```
import time
import random
from collections import deque
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

T = 20
B = 5
REPLAY_MINIMUM_SIZE = 10
REPLAY_MAXIMUM_SIZE = 100


class Actor:
    def __init__(self, global_buffer, rank):
        self.rank = rank
        self.local_buffer = []
        self.global_buffer = global_buffer

    def run(self, num_steps):
        for step in range(num_steps):
            data = f'{self.rank}_{step}'
            self.local_buffer.append(data)

            if len(self.local_buffer) >= B:
                self.global_buffer.put(self.local_buffer)
                self.local_buffer = []


class Learner:
    def __init__(self, replay):
        self.replay = replay

    def run(self, num_steps):
        while self.replay.size() <= REPLAY_MINIMUM_SIZE:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        for step in range(num_steps):
            batch = self.replay.sample(B)
            print(batch)

class Replay:
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=capacity)

    def push(self, experiences):
        self.memory.extend(experiences)

    def sample(self, n):
        return random.sample(self.memory, n)

    def size(self):
        return len(self.memory)


def send_data_to_replay(global_buffer, replay):
    while True:
        if not global_buffer.empty():
            batch = global_buffer.get()
            replay.push(batch)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_actors = 2

    global_buffer = mp.Queue()

    BaseManager.register("ReplayMemory", Replay)
    Manager = BaseManager()
    Manager.start()
    replay = Manager.ReplayMemory(REPLAY_MAXIMUM_SIZE)

    learner = Learner(replay)
    learner_process = mp.Process(target=learner.run, args=(T,))
    learner_process.start()

    actor_processes = []
    for rank in range(num_actors):
        p = mp.Process(target=Actor(global_buffer, rank).run, args=(T,))
        p.start()
        actor_processes.append(p)

    replay_process = mp.Process(target=send_data_to_replay, args=(global_buffer, replay,))
    replay_process.start()

    learner_process.join()
    [actor_process.join() for actor_process in actor_processes]
    replay_process.join()
```

I followed several tutorials and read websites related to multiprocessing, but I am very new to distributed computing. I am not sure if what I am doing is right.

I wanted to know if there is some malpractice in my code or things that are not following good practices. Moreover, when I launch the program, **the different processes do not terminate**. And I am not sure why and how to handle it.

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I find that when working with multiprocessing it is best to have a Queue for each running process. When you are ready to close the application you can send an exit message ( or poison pill )  to each queue and close each process cleanly.

When you launch a child process pass the parent queue and the child queue to the new process through inheritance.

Comment: I will try to see if I will implement that, but since the goal is to make all the data converge to the Replay, I thought that it was quite nice to have only one Queue. Why do you believe it is best to have several?  
I don't understand the sentence about child process, parents and child queue, can you explain a little bit more ?

Comment: I see, I would make sure all the child process have a reference to the Replay queue and therefore the Replay process. 

A parent process would be the first process launched, a child process would be one launched BY the parent process. In this case, and especially if you are using the Actor paradigm the parent process should always manage the child process it launches. Check out thespian https://thespianpy.com/doc/ they have implemented a lot of this stuff (queue management)  so you don't have to.